# Free OS other than Linux

Tags: operating-systems

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are some alternative desktop operating systems?](https://superuser.com/questions/37117/what-are-some-alternative-desktop-operating-systems)

Are there any other free OS other than Linux? Free for desktop and individual use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not ready for everyday use yet, but take a look at [ReactOS](http://www.reactos.org/en/index.html).

Also the various BSD variants:  [FreeBSD](http://www.freebsd.org/), [OpenBSD](http://www.openbsd.org/), [NetBSD](http://www.netbsd.org/)...  but these are all very similar to linux.

What are you looking for that linux does not do?

Comment: beat me to the BSD variants.. :p

Comment: Linux serves everything, just asking. Want to try it as well.

Comment: No mention of OpenSolaris? Shocking! :O

Comment: No mention of Pirated Windows?....;-)

Comment: @mick: I already asked about OpenSolaris in one of my earlier posts. That's why didn't mention it again.

Answer (score 5):

See here: [Comparison of open source operating systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_open_source_operating_systems)

Answer (score 1):

For a rather different experience (not based on Unix), look at [Haiku](http://haiku-os.org/). I'm definitely keeping my eye on that one.

Comment: I loved beOS and was sad to see it go. Haiku is getting there but the last time I used it (although it was quite a bit ago) it just didn't seem the same.

Comment: I also liked BeOS. There was so much hype. After that it disappeared. But don't know how rich is the community at Haiku.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do anything near production, I would probably look at the BSD variants that Joel mentioned above.

You can also still get [OpenSolaris](http://hub.opensolaris.org/bin/view/Main/) although it's future is probably non-existant now that Oracle killed it. [Solaris Express 11](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solaris11/overview/index.html) has some license limitations - supposed to be for Test/Dev only and you're supposed to buy a support contract/subscription for production use.